# My provisioning profile not showing when submitting app to App Store through XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

So I am following the Submitting Guide on Apples homepage to submit my app, but when I am trying Product -> Archive -> Validate I need to choose a profile to sign in with. I sign in with my Developer Account but I am met with a information box that I should choose a Provisioning Profile. (I have two accounts, one for work and one for private. I never use the work one but got one from our ios dev some month ago). [Screen on how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9n6S.jpg)

Anyway, I deleted my work account in Xcode and I got two provisioning profiles for Distribution downloaded and added to my private account. I can see them in Preferences -> Accounts

What can I do to submit my app?? I am lost..

I have tried to remove all certificates and profiles and recreated them but to no luck.

Comment: I'm confused. You want to know why the provisioning profile isn't showing up?

Comment: Yes.. it shows in my Member Center and it shows in Preference -> Account -> View Details in XCode but not in that dropdown list and yes, I have refreshed in XCode.

Comment: Did you create new version of the app in the iTunes Connect site?

Comment: Yes, I have done that and it is in status Waiting for Upload.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work by removing all profiles from Developer Portal a few times and recreated it and suddenly it just worked. I saw my provisioning profile and could validate my app.